# Cannot update IAM policy through CloudFormation - Status Code 500

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have an `AWS::IAM::RolePolicy` defined on CloudFormation, something like this:

```
  AllowSchedulerToExecuteCodePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::RolePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        {
           "Version": "2012-10-17",
           "Statement": [
              {
                 "Sid": "ExecuteLambdaFunctions",
                 "Effect": "Allow",
                 "Action": [
                   "lambda:InvokeFunction"
                 ],
                 "Resource": [
                   "Fn::GetAtt": "Lambda1.Arn",
                   "Fn::GetAtt": "Lambda2.Arn"
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "Sid": "ExecuteECSTask",
                 "Effect": "Allow",
                 "Action": [
                   "ecs:StartTask",
                   "ecs:StopTask",
                 ],
                 "Resource": [
                   "Fn::GetAtt": "ECSCluster1.Arn"
                 ]
             }
           ]
        }
      PolicyName: !Sub Invoke-Code-${Environment}
      RoleName: !Ref EventBridgeSchedulerExecutionRole
```

I now want to remove Lambda2.Arn from the Cloudformation stack. So I removed the reference to it in the policy as well.

When I try and update the new RolePolicy through CloudFormation, I get the following error:
`Resource handler returned message: "null (Service: Iam, Status Code: 500, Request ID: d2b80ce2-5289-4509-8967-3a65409f8282)" (RequestToken: 06927047-00b6-378d-78c9-65105e880242, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)`

The subsequent update rollback is showing the same error, and now I am stuck with a broken stack.

Any idea on what is causing this issue? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself after a while... It seems the IAM service had a hiccup.

For those having the same issue, try and deploy the stack after waiting. If that doesn't work, maybe try renaming the resource so that it triggers a resource replacement instead of a resource update.